# Job won't run until I restrict where it can run

Tags: jenkins

I have an empty job in Jenkins, and when I try to "build" it, it just sits there "waiting for next available executor".

I can only get it to run when I select "restrict where this project can be run" and give it specific node (or group of nodes) to run on.

Is this supposed to work like that?  If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest to review all your jenkins node configuration

there is a specific selector at the node level about usage

choices are :

- Leave this machine for tied jobs only
- Utilize this slave as much as possible

If all your nodes restrict the access to tied jobs only, that would explain your problem